# Angular 2: i18n of strings in source code

Tags: angular, internationalization

In official NG2 docs described the way to translate text inside html templates [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html). However it is sometimes necessary to translate text strings in source code also. i.e. string passed to alert() function.

How to implement it with official i18n support?

Comment: There's no way currently AFAIK. Dynamic i18n should be done with third-party tools, e.g. ng2-translate

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075872/4399281